# What is the encrypted data size for RSA encryption using blocks

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have c# code which uses BouncyCastle library to do RSA encryption:

```
public string EncryptData(string publicKey, string data)
{
    try
    {
        var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        int srclen = bytesToEncrypt.Length;

        //Prepare encryption engine
        var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

        //Initialize Key
        using (var txtreader = new StringReader(publicKey))
        {
            var keyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();
            encryptEngine.Init(true, keyParameter);
        }

        //Encrypt in loop
        byte[] complete = new byte[0];
        int src_block_size = encryptEngine.GetInputBlockSize();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < srclen; idx += src_block_size)
        {
            int data_len = srclen - idx;
            if (data_len > src_block_size)
            {
                data_len = src_block_size;
            }

            var encryptedChunk = encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToEncrypt, idx, data_len);
            complete = CombineByteArrays(complete, encryptedChunk);
        }

        var finalString = Convert.ToBase64String(complete);
        return finalString;
    }
    catch (InvalidCipherTextException)
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see it chunks the data into blocks and encrypts each block. When I encrypt the data I can see that the `finalstring` is a variable size (please note that `finalString` is basically a base64 encoding of the encrypted bytes). Not sure what is the factor deciding the length and if it is a set pattern that I can rely on or it is indefinite. I need to make sure that the `finalString` is within a limit (number of characters).

Comment: Using RSA as a block cipher is a really poor idea just FYI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of an encrypted **RSA** block is dictated by the key size. The amount of data that can be encrypted in a **RSA** block is at the same time also dependent of the size of the **RSA** key minus the amount of data taken up by the padding.

Generally **RSA** should not be used for bulk encryption as it's quite slow (could be a factor 1000) and have an overhead on each block due to the padding (which you should use). If you actually need the benefit of the two key's in **RSA**, you should use a [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) approach. If you actually don't need the two keys, then you properly need to use a symmetric cipher like **AES**. Also, When using symmetric encryption you will get support for blocking right out of the box, as opposed to what you have with **RSA**.

Comment: So the input data will never exceed 5kb for us so, from what I have read, it should be okay to use RSA encryption. The key size we are using is 1024 bit. So here is my question, considering that I am also doing base64 encoding, is there a fixed pattern by which base64 encoding increases the data size? Or should I, to be safe, assume that base64 encoding will further increase the length by 40%?

Comment: When you use more than one RSA block you are mis-using RSA. From a security point of view, a 1024 bit RSA key is way too small. Also, who is going to decrypt this - same person that encrypted it ? If same person/system then you actually don't need two keys - making the use of RSA overkill - then a symmetric approach like AES would be more suited. 
 As for the Base64 encoding: it increases the output by approx. 33%.

Comment: That answers my questions I suppose. Thanks